# Reversing a reverse match lookup logic to avoid use of helper row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been awake too long and/or my mind is fried.  I managed to get what I am trying to do with the help of a helper row, but I cant figure out how to reverse the formula/function to work in the other direction and avoid the helper row

### Objective

Determine the last vehicle wheel on a surface given:

1. the vehicle is driving in a straight line perpendicular to the starting edge of the surface (think of it as a vehicle driving along a line).
2. the vehicle axles ordinates are supplied relative to the lead axle.
3. the distance traveled by the lead axle away from the start point is
       given.
4. the length of the surface is given (though probably not
       required).
5. the overall length of vehicle is given (ie axle 1 to axle
       5)
6. the number of axles can vary but will be defined in the same
       table

### Vehicle Definition

```
         (B)       (C)    (D)    (E)    (F)    (G)
(7)     Axle        1      2      3      4      5
(8)     Ordinate    0    3.6    4.8   11.4     18

(10)    HelperRow  18   14.4   13.2    6.6      0



       (B)              (C)     (D)
(11)   Surface Length    8
(13)   Truck length             18
```

The table has also been configured using named ranges as follows:

```
Truck_Definition as $C$7:$G$9
Axle_Header as $C$7:$G$7
Axle_Ordinates as $C8:$G$8
Span as $C$11
```

### Equations so far

The helper row is simply reversing the ordinate direction from the front of the truck to the rear of the truck. In C10 I placed the following formula and copied right

```
=Truck_Length-C8
```

Way over to the right of the spreadsheet where I am developing a whole whack (that is the technical term right?) of columns for intermediate calculations.  Column AA rows 13 to 27 holds the distance the front axle has traveled.  So my first task for myself was to determine the lead axle number.  I could have done it through series of nested if then statement but that makes the equations look really ugly sometimes and hard to decipher.  My lead axle number formula in AB13, which I then copied down through ABAB27, looks like this:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(AA13-Span,Axle_Ordinates,1)+1,1)
```

I thought it was pretty simple and it works nicely. Just had to set an error catch since the match lookup method returns the axle before the one I want meaning if I want axle 1 it will be out of range or not fund type deal.

So I then turned my attention to look for a nice slick formula to do it from the reverse direction.  With the addition of the helper row I came up with this in AC13 and copied it down through to AC27:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(W13,$C$10:$G$10,-1),99)
```

I tossed in the 99 just in case there was an error but so far it has not shown up on my list.  I think it is working, I have not broken it yet, but I have not tried much.  And apparently I did not define my W column:

```
=Truck_Length-AA13
```

Oh yes, nearly forgot.  If it helps somehow, there is an index column in K13:K27 that has the sequential integers 1 to 15.

### What I want to know

**Is there a way to calculate the second last equation for determining the trailing axle without using a helper row or a long winded string of nested if then statements?**

### Extra Info

This is a screen shot of the set up info describe above for lets call it Vehicle 1.

[image: Vehicle 1]

and lets call this Vehicle 3

[image: Vehicle 3]

The change is based on a drop down selection in D4

And in case it happens to help someone this is a snap shot of my current work area.  The 3 testing columns in the middle will eventually be deleted. I am going to look at combining columns as well.  All that to get 3 yes marks in the AD column!  Sadly through hopefully half as many columns it will spit out 1 number.

And yes, so much simpler to do via VBA, but not going there and sticking to formulas.

[image: Work Area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula ...

```
{=IFNA(MATCH(W13,Truck_Length-$C$8:$G$8,-1),99)}
```

I get these results, in the highlighted background - as compared to your original results ...

[image]

**Updated for Non-CSE solution**

How about this ...

```
=MATCH(Truck_Length-W13,Axle_Ordinates,1)
```

I get the same results as in the previous pic.

Comment: Thanks,  I have an aversion to CSE formulas, but sometimes its the only fit.  You had me scratching my head, or rahter I did.  I have been working on my spreadsheet since I posted.  When I compared your numbers to my current sheet, they were not lining up with my current data.  Then I remembered I rearranged the rows so that when a truck with no axle 5 on it at the bottom and then the combination with no 4 above that.  That way when the different trucks are selected I can make the bottom of the table disappear instead of random rows.

Comment: This does answer my question as stated.  Can you think of a non CSE way of doing it? And "no" is an acceptable answer! 8)  and Kudos to you for going the extra mile and positioning everything the way I had it and using named range too!

Comment: I am currently racking the old noggin to think of a way to maybe toss it inside an aggregate or sumproduct type function to get it to do the array calc.

Comment: OMG! I must have danced around the combination for hours last night.  Apparently stating awake 20+ hours on a regular basis fogs the mind!

Comment: Sorry, I can only up vote and accept your answer once 8)  I hate that feeling of knowing there is a way to do it and being so close but just cant quite get there.  Thank you for the assist.

Comment: I know what that's like.

Comment: I simplified the equation event further.  Since W13 `=Truck_Length-AA13`, Truck length cancels itself and the non CSE formula becomes `=MATCH(AA13,Axle_Ordinates,1)`...See what happens when I get some sleep 8)